# CarbonInterval using Carbon - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I don't know how to implement CarbonInterval in laravel 4.2; I don't know where to place this code.

```
<?php
class CarbonInterval extends \DateInterval
{
    // code here
}
```

And test using

```
echo CarbonInterval::months(3);
```

I don't know whether I will create a class and add it to the classmap in composer or I will just add it to the Carbon.php

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding the question correctly. Why would you create the CarbonInterval class? It's a part of the Carbon package.

Comment: Here is the website http://iitcebu.net/attendance I already implemented carbon perfectly but I need to know how to use CarbonInterval. It doesn't work if I use CarbonInterval::months(3)

Comment: Documentation is not clear about CarbonIntervall install, I did not understood either... CarbonIntervall is available since tag [1.18.0](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/tree/1.18.0/src/Carbon).

Answer (score 0):

From the **docs**: [CarbonInterval](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval)

You should *not* override any Carbon classes, because that will mess stuff up. Instead, read the docs!

What we can see from the docs:

```
echo CarbonInterval::year();                           // 1 year
echo CarbonInterval::months(3);                        // 3 months
echo CarbonInterval::days(3)->seconds(32);             // 3 days 32 seconds
echo CarbonInterval::weeks(3);                         // 3 weeks
echo CarbonInterval::days(23);                         // 3 weeks 2 days
echo CarbonInterval::create(2, 0, 5, 1, 1, 2, 7);      // 2 years 5 weeks 1 day 1 hour 2 minutes 7 seconds
```

So, basically: avoid redefining classes that are already in the library. Your code should work fine, all you have to do is import `Carbon\CarbonInterval`, and call one or more of the static methods. `CarbonInterval` [does implement `__toString()`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/CarbonInterval.php#L494), so you can simply use `echo` (or `print`) with the method call, and it will work.

You shouldn't need to include Carbon with Composer, as you can see from the 4.2 Eloquent documentation that Carbon is already included.

Hopefully I helped! This happens to be my first time attempting to answer a question on here :)